# how to use swc file in flash builder project

Tags: java, apache-flex, swc

HI..
i have a  swc file i have added file to my project using 
http://interactivesection.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/use_flash_code_library_in_flex.jpg
how can i use this component in my flash builder project.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the swc to the project as shown in your screengrab, you can just use any of the classes in the swc as you would any other class in your project:

AS:

```
import some.package.in.my.swc.SomeClass;

private var someClass:SomeClass;
```

MXML:

Add a namespace to the top level tag that points to a package in the swc, such as xmlns:library="some.package.in.my.swc.*", then add tags like so:

```
<library:SomeComponent/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do I figure out what is the package name that I need to import ? I have a *.swc file and followed the same steps as described by @user594979. In my package explorer, the *.swc file shows up in my Referenced Libraries folder. But then I need to import it and unfortunately don't have the name of the package ?

Answer (score 1):

Project Properties | Flex Build Path | Add SWC

and then to use a component import it in your ActionScript class